# exists() Always Returning False In Android Application Using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to remove all files from a directory before downloading a new file to the same location. I am trying to run a check to see if the file exists before I execute a delete. Even though I know the file exists, it always seems to come back as false.

Here is the code that downloads the file:

```
    val url = "www.fileurl.com"
    val filename = "trainingvideos.zip";

    val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
    request.setTitle("Download")
    request.setDescription("The file is downloading...")

    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(applicationContext, "TrainingVideos", filename)

    val manager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager

    manager.enqueue(request)
```

Which downloads the file to "Local/Internal storage/Android/data/com.example.mypackage/files/TrainingVideos".

Before the download I want to check to see if the file exists. I have tried setting the path a few different ways and I suspect that's where I may be going wrong, no matter what I do exists() always comes back false:

```
    val directory = "Internal storage/Android/data/com.example.mypackage/files/TrainingVideos/trainingvideos.zip"

    var directoryToDelete = File(directory)

    var exists = directoryToDelete.exists()

    if ( exists ) {

        directoryToDelete.deleteRecursively()
    }
```

Comment: That is no valid path to begin with. Have a look at getExternalFilesDir(null).

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips. I had found that path by navigating the files on the physical device I am using to debug. I was able to solve the problem after checking out getExternalFilesDir(null).